# A string doesn't have the attribute .loc

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ohlc

I have different dataframes that follow the example: 'AAPLdf, AMZNdf, GOOGLdf, ...' etc
I just want to be able to enter the ticker as an input so that I don't have write the same code a million times.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates
```

```
ticker = input("ticker:") + "df"
```

```
data = ticker
ohlc = data.loc[:, ['t', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c']]
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: I couldn't understand what do you want to do here, ```loc``` is not a method for a string. let me know what you want to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is a built-in python function
- `f'{variable}'` is an f-string

  - [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
  - [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```py
ticker = input('ticker: ')

# this will return data as the dataframe from ticker, but it must be an exact match
data = eval(f'{ticker}df')  # -> equivalent to eval('GOOGLdf`), for example

# now you can use .loc 
data.loc[:, :]
```